# Interacting with a Javascript object where the keys are number date/times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with an api that gives data about transportation schedules, and the response is organized by dates with times nested inside the dates.  A response looks something like the following:

```
object = {
  2016-07-27: {
    09:30:00: {
      // data here
    }
    13:00:00: {
      // data here
    }
  }
  2016-07-28: {
    09:30:00: {
      // data here
    }
    13:00:00: {
      // data here
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to get into the time objects to get the data I need.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: my problem was that i couldn't access the time property within each date object- but i just remembered i can use bracket notation

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(date => Object.keys(object[date]).forEach(time => {
    const value = object[date][time]; // values iteration
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of how you would iterate through an object's properties.

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

hasOwnProperty is necessary because an object's prototype contains additional properties for the object which are technically part of the object.

Source: [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)